# can't connect my .css file to my .html file?

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to programming, and I'm learning HTML and CSS (don't know much about DOM yet), but I heard that using separate files for CSS stylesheets is a great way to organize, so I stopped using  tags, and made a new file for my css code. But when I try to use a  tag, it doesn't link my .css file to my .html file. My html file and my css file is in the same directory/folder. I use a chromebook, and use Caret/Material Neutron. This is my link tag: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />` Is there anything wrong with it?

EDIT: I figured it out. I moved on and learned how to make a link in an html file leading to another html file, using an anchor tag, and I learned that for some reason, I have to link using the URL that shows up in the search bar on google when I open a file to preview what it looks like, which is weird, but it works! And then, I realized that I can do that with my .css file, and after copy and pasting the url into a `<link>` tag (but modifying the last part of the url from index.html to style.css), the CSS worked! It's weird, but good enough. But is that the *right* way to make different html pages?

Comment: @stig-js "My html file and my css file is in the same directory." I'd say so.

Comment: Yes, they're both in the same folder.

Comment: It looks fine and should work if, as you say, both files are in the same directory. Can we see the css and your html?

Comment: Is it perhaps the trailing `/` at the end?

Comment: @Darkrifts — No. That's a bit of harmless syntax for the hopelessly XML addicted.

Comment: Maybe you CSS file is invalid, could you post it?

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to identify a problem. Provide a [MCVE]. Use the developer tools in your browser. Check the Network tab to make sure the stylesheet is being loaded. Check the console for error messages (Firefox's console can be configured to display CSS errors).

Comment: You can check if your file is connected or not using view source in browser of html file and in link tag your file will be shown as link. Try to open it

Comment: I think you need to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475068/node-js-not-reading-my-css-file

Answer (score -1):

The style.css and your html file must be in the same folder to use it this way, and the css file must not include the style tags, just styles.

Comment: It is in the same folder.

Comment: They aren't in any style tags