# Node js not reading my CSS file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am trying to read an html file from node Js server script but its not reading a css file which i linked in the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My node file</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class = "home">
    <h2>Hello there</h2>
    <p>Iam developing my first node js site</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS**

```
.home{
    background: red;
}
```

**My Node js File**

```
    var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080
```

**What i expect**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlOd4.png)

**What am getting**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImRgC.png)

Any help is warmly appreciated

Comment: Why should it? The only code you have to read any file is hard coded to read `index.html`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you answer every request with `index.html`. That means if the web browser sends a request for `style.css` it still gets the html. You could look into your browsers console to verify this. To serve different files, you might wanna check [`request.url`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) to serve exactly the file the client wants to:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
 if(req.url === "/index.html" || req.url === "/"){
  fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
     res.write(data);
     res.end();
   });
 } else if(req.url === "/style.css"){
   fs.readFile('style.css', function(err, data) {
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
     res.write(data);
     res.end();
   });
 }
}).listen(8080);
```

If you think that gets nasty for many different files, you may use a library that allows static directory serving, e.g. [express](http://expressjs.com)

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to serve that css as a static file on the server side, like:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

here you just say, hey client side from now on the path of my things inside the public folder can be catched like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
```

if you have a css folder this is the way you get the styling, now in your client side just link to that

Comment: OP is not using express!